# Magento: Getting the Value of an EAV Attribute Option/Select

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

I Have an object of Mage_Customer_Model_Customer and ran the following code:

```
$customer->loadByEmail($customer->getEmail());
$customer->getGender();  //returns the EAV attribute option_id's of 1 or 2
```

I am trying to get the eav_attribute_option_value.value of those option_id's which is the word "Male" or the word "Female"

I am not sure how to do this and spent quite a bit of time debugging the account form select widget with no success.  I am also curious on how you figured this out.

Thanks in advance

Sincerly,
Tired Dev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$attributeOptions = $customer->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($attributeOptions); echo "</pre>";
```

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-attribute-name-and-value/

EDIT: From Link:

```
$entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType('invoice');
$entityTypeId = $entityType->getEntityTypeId();

$attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                ->setCodeFilter('order_id')
                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                ->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: I was looking for the selected option, this link provided just that.  Thanks!